# What do you call such kind of food/drink?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If we feel tired or weak, we have some kind of food like chocolate or tea to make ourselves active or fresh. Is there any particular word or phrase for such food?

Comment: The expression 'a refreshing cup of tea' is virtually a set phrase.

Comment: To add to Edwin's comment 'refreshment/s'

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jvCTaccEkMI

Comment: Related, but maybe not a direct answer - "snack".  Something to eat between meals, often for energy or a treat.

Comment: You can consider "x-boosting (food/drink)". For example, energy-boosting or mood-boosting...

Comment: What is wrong with "refreshment"?

Answer (score 41):

You might call it a "[pick-me-up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pick-me-up)."

Comment: Can it be used for illicit drugs?

Comment: @Centaurus, yes.

Comment: That [depends on your location](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_alcohol_prohibition) @Centaurus; [possibly cf. Portugal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_policy_of_Portugal).

Answer (score 15):

**"invigorating"** is the word I would use.

- "An invigorating drink/cup of coffee."

> - [**invigorate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/invigorating) - "to impart vigor, strength, or vitality to; animate"
>
> "A few whiffs of the raw, strong scent of phlox invigorated her" (D.H. Lawrence).
>
> "The bright sun and invigorating northern air made me feel much better"

but you might also use **"energizing"**

> - [**"energizer"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/energizing) -  "something that gives energy to, activates or invigorates.
>
> "I feel so slow today, I guess I need an energizing drink"

Answer (score 8):

Anything in general that restores energy is a *restorative*, such as "a restorative piece of chocolate" or "a restorative nap." I disagree slightly with the suggestion of *refreshment* since that's passed into a more general sense of any food or beverage, especially that provided to guests, but the literal meaning is there. A *stimulant* potentially carries connotations of being pharmaceutical, but not always (e.g. caffeine is a stimulant, but so is a nice hot cup of coffee).

As far as adjectives go, "invigorating," "revitalizing," "energizing," and "rejuvenating" can all be used to describe any food that provides that effect to the describer. I think you may be looking for a noun that describes a genre of food generally accepted to be used for that purpose, and to that end I recommend "pick-me-up" (colloquial) or "restorative" (the most natural of the nominalized adjectives, to my ear).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the venerable 1931 culinary classic, *Joy of Cooking*, categorizes such things as restoratives.

Answer (score 7):

I'll go with **stimulant** and **stimulating** [food or beverage].

> stimulant: any food or beverage that [**stimulates**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stimulate), especially coffee,
>   tea, or, in its initial effect, alcoholic liquor.

[**Random House Dictionary**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stimulant)

Also, you might want to say, *I need a cup of strong, hot tea (or coffee or whatever) for a **kick***.

> kick: the sudden stimulation provided by strong drink (or certain
>   drugs); *a sidecar is a smooth drink but it has a powerful kick*

[**Princeton University, Farlex Inc.**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kick)

Answer (score 3):

***[High-energy food/drinks](http://www.prevention.com/food/healthy-eating-tips/high-energy-foods-jump-start-your-day)*** are expressions used to refer to food or drinks consumed when  you feel tired and need a small boost.

> - You don't need a PhD in biochemistry to know that food is fuel and that it affects our energy levels. But you have to be smart if you're eating for energy. "Certain eating strategies will definitely help you ward off fatigue," says Stacey Whittle, RD, a registered dietitian at the University of Southern California in Los Angeles.

(www.prevention.com)